# Terraform Error - Inappropriate Value for attribute : string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

> When executing terraform apply , getting below error. 
> I am very new to terraform , please excuse me. 
> I am trying to create the following buckets in AWS s3 using terraform script. 
> Any suggestions to fix the error ?

1. x-d-dev/some/IN/
2. x-d-dev/some/OUT/
3. x-d-qa/some/IN/
4. x-d-qa/some/OUT/
5. x-d-prod/some/IN/
6. x-d-prod/some/OUT/

```
    variable "s3_bucket_env" {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["x-d-dev", "x-d-qa","x-d-prod"]

    }

    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
    count         = length(var.s3_bucket_env) //count will be 3
    bucket        = var.s3_bucket_env[count.index]
    acl           = "private"
    }

    variable "s3_bucket_names" {
    type = list
    default = ["some/IN/", "some/OUT/"]
    }

    resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "some_s3_bucket" {
    count         = length(var.s3_bucket_names) //count will be 3
    bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.b[count.index]
    key           = var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]
    acl           = "private"
    }
```

> error

````
PS C:\S3\S3_Creation\another-optiin> terraform apply
aws_s3_bucket.b[0]: Refreshing state... [id=x-d-dev]
aws_s3_bucket_object.x_s3_buckets[1]: Refreshing state... [id=some/OUT/]
aws_s3_bucket_object.x_s3_buckets[0]: Refreshing state... [id=some/IN/]

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

on 1.tf line 49, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "x_s3_buckets":
49:   bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.b[count.index]
  |----------------
  | aws_s3_bucket.b is tuple with 3 elements
  | count.index is 1

Inappropriate value for attribute "bucket": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

```on 1.tf line 49, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "x_s3_buckets":
49:   bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.b[count.index]
     |----------------
     | aws_s3_bucket.b is tuple with 3 elements
     | count.index is 0

 Inappropriate value for attribute "bucket": string required.```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're currently passing an entire bucket object, when you should be passing the bucket name only.

Change this:

```
 bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.b[count.index]
```

To this:

```
 bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.b[count.index].bucket
```

Comment: That worked but did not create all the folders which i expected. ```                             
1) x-d-dev/some/IN/

2) x-d-dev/some # /OUT missing

3) x-d-qa/some

4) x-d-qa/some/OUT/

5) x-d-prod # some//OUT missing

6) x-d-prod #some//IN missing      
````